# What is wrong with this code, trying a click menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So there is a left side vertical menu. And it has a small options button. When clicked, it should open a div which will have various filter options. Now, i need it to appear when clicked, and disappear when either the options button is clicked again, or the user clicks anywhere outside the div.

So i have the following code.

```
//options filter menu animation
$('#optionsmenu').hide(); //hides the menu

$('.optionsfilters').click(function(e){
    var $this = $('#optionsmenu');
    $this.show();
    var left = $('#sidebar').css('width'),
        top = $(this).offset().top;
    $this.css('top', top);
    $this.css('left', left);
});
$(':not(.optionsfilters)').click(function(e){
    $('#optionsmenu').hide();
});
```

The HTML is

```
<div id="sidebartitle">
    <h2>Organisation</h2>
    <a id="optionsfilters" class="optionsfilters">Options</a>
</div>
<div id="optionsmenu" class="optionsfilters">
    <h3>Add New</h3>
    <ul>
        <label>Year</label>
        <select>
            <option>2000</option>
            <option>2001</option>
            <option>2002</option>
            <option>2003</option>
            <option>2004</option>
            <option>2005</option>
        </select>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Its not working together, i.e. the two javascript functions, the first one works alone, when the second one is commented out. The second one works, if i comment out the hide part, and add an alert message. But together, they don't work.

Whats the conflict?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if the person who down voted, at least specify explain my stupidity...

Comment: If you place a console.log in each function, are they both triggered when you click on the button? My guess is that both functions are called when you clicked on the button...

Comment: if any of the answers below answered your question please mark it as accepted

Comment: Hey, sorry, had to leave the desk. Will mark as soon as i understand the various answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there are a few things you will want to do:

1) If you want the original button to close the menu you will want to use `.toggle()` rather than `.show()`

2) You will want to detect a click on the document, to hide the options menu. Which will not be called if it is the options menu that is clicked due to the `e.stopPropagation();` (point 4 below).

```
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#optionsmenu').hide();
    });
```

3) You also want to check (as both have the same class) that the `.optionsfilters` that was clicked was not the filters themselves (otherwise this will stop you clicking an option).

```
    if( e.target !== this ) {
       return;
    }
```

4) Use `e.stopPropagation();` to stop the event bubbling up to the parents (or document).

This should be what you are looking for:

```
$('#optionsmenu').hide(); //hides the menu

$('.optionsfilters').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if( e.target !== this ) {
       return;
    }
    var $this = $('#optionsmenu');

    $this.toggle();
    var left = $('#sidebar').css('width'),
       top = $(this).offset().top;
    $this.css('top', top);
    $this.css('left', left);
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $('#optionsmenu').hide();
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/pny4vq26/

Comment: Thanks, i tried to understand what the e.stopPropagation(); is doing here. Is this explaination correct?   

Once the selected target is clicked, it will not add any more clicks to the queue. I think i'm wrong here, cause thats what the stop() does.

Comment: Or is it this, while the function is in progress, another attempt to start another instance/restart the function will be stopped? But then whats the if statement for? What is that doing?

Comment: Sorry should have explained. This is to prevent event bubbling. So after the click event is fired for the element, it stops the click events that might be attached to other parent elements from being executed. The `e` in `e.stopPropagation();` is defined whilst declaring the function. You could declare this as any var name, but `e` or `event` is the coding standard. To which point, the `$('html:not(.optionsfilters)')` could simply be written as `$('html')` (or equally `$(document)`) as the event should not bubble up to them. (Think I simply solved that part first). Updated fiddle and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
//options filter menu animation
var filters = $('.optionsfilters');
var options = $('#optionsmenu');

options.hide(); //hides the menu

filters.click(function(e){
    $('#optionsmenu').toggle();
    var left = $('#sidebar').css('width'),
        top = $(this).offset().top;
    _this.css('top', top);
    _this.css('left', left);
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!filters.is(e.target) && filters.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        options.hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e86hdwc/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mainly that both your click handlers run and one shows the menu then the other one hides it.

Why? Because that's not a good selector. Until you reach the element with the class *.optionsfilters* your click goes through *body*, *#sidebartitle* and then it reaches the element *a*. And since the parents of that element don't have the class *.optionsfilters*, it will hide the menu.

So I changed the code a little. First of all don't use the class as a click handler. Use the IDs

```
$('#optionsfilters').click(function (e) { // ID of options
    var $this = $('#optionsmenu');
    $this.toggle(); // toggle show/hide when click on it
    var left = $('#sidebar').css('width'),
        top = $(this).offset().top;
    $this.css('top', top);
    $this.css('left', left);
});
```

The you need to check when you click outside of the *#optionsmenu*. For that you attach a click handler on document and check the *e.target*

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.optionsfilters').length)
         $('#optionsmenu').hide();
});
```

If the *e.target* itself is **not** *.optionsfilters* and is not a child of a parent with that class then you hide the menu.

Working example below.

```js
//options filter menu animation
$('#optionsmenu').hide(); //hides the menu

$('#optionsfilters').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $('#optionsmenu');
    $this.toggle();
    var left = $('#sidebar').css('width'),
        top = $(this).offset().top;
    $this.css('top', top);
    $this.css('left', left);
});
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.optionsfilters').length) $('#optionsmenu').hide();
});
```

```css
#optionsmenu{
  background:lightblue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebartitle">
     <h2>Organisation</h2>
 <a id="optionsfilters" class="optionsfilters">Options</a>

</div>
<div id="optionsmenu" class="optionsfilters">
     <h3>Add New</h3>

    <ul>
        <label>Year</label>
        <select>
            <option>2000</option>
            <option>2001</option>
            <option>2002</option>
            <option>2003</option>
            <option>2004</option>
            <option>2005</option>
        </select>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, your code works fine. But the other answer taught me a new thing. So upvoting yours, but cannot mark as best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a classic demonstration of stopPropagation in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

here is a fiddle that simplify this: http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/98082xk7/1/

in short:

```
$('.optionsfilters').click(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation(); // or elese it will fire the parent event
    var $this = $('#optionsmenu');
    $this.show();
    var left = $('#sidebar').css('width'),
        top = $(this).offset().top;
    $this.css('top', top);
    $this.css('left', left);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using :not for *any* other elements, because if - for example - you click the dropdown, the sidebar hides again, which I doubt you want to happen.

It'd be better to define areas you want to make the sidebar hide when clicked, like the main content area.

Also since you use the class `.optionsfilters` on your sidebar menu, when you click in there the sidebar will hide again.

Try this
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw2vz1gw/).

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand, but if your menu is hide (first instruction in your js), how can you click on it for show it?

EDIT: Didn't noticed the class attriute on previous div. My fault.